# 'firebase init' gives me a generic error on a ionic project

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-tools

I'm following a course of ionic and I need to store a picture on firebase database, at that point we should install firebase-tools, which I do by executing as admin:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

But then the course says you should execute:

```
firebase init
```

and then I receive the following error:

> Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

This generic error with nothing else.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute:

```
firebase init --debug
```

This gives you more info about the error.

It might be something about credentials or login information which can be solved by executing:

```
firebase login
```

Comment: You are right, the error was: `Error: Could not load the default credentials.` and with that `firebase login` command it works. Thank you!